# Returning dataset with PL/SQL and a variable table name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL function to store a select statement with a variable table name (a bit weird i know but it is actually a good design decision). The following code does not work...but I'm not sure how to both take a variable table name (building the query) and return a dataset. Anyone have any experience in this? TIA.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_netstat_all (casename in varchar2) 
RETURN  resultset_subtype
IS
  dataset resultset_subtype;
  v_sql varchar2(25000);
  v_tablename varchar2(50);

begin

  v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM ' || casename || '_netstat;'; 

  OPEN dataset FOR
    execute immediate v_sql;
  return dataset;

end;
```

Comment: Are all table structures identical ? If they are not you can't use [native dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/dynamic.htm#i13130) (that's what you're using above) but have to rely on [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm) PL/SQL package.

Answer (score 1):

If your resultset_subtype is a ref_cursor (or just replace resultset_subtype with a ref_cursor) you could:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION fn_netstat_all (
   casename IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN resultset_subtype
IS
   dataset resultset_subtype;
BEGIN
   OPEN dataset
   FOR 'SELECT * FROM ' || casename || '_netstat';

   RETURN dataset;
END fn_netstat_all;
```

FWIW, you might want to look into the DBMS_ASSERT package to wrap the casename variable to help protect against SQL Injection attacks in your dynamic SQL.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Ollie, that function does not work. It is giving me an invalid character error in the line:

OPEN dataset FOR 'SELECT * FROM ' || casename || '_netstat;';

Comment: @coergo You have extra semi-colon (;). The correct form is `'SELECT * FROM ' || casename || '_netstat';`

Answer (score 1):

Below it is assumed all tables are similar. It's also possible to select a subset of colums that are similar in every table without using [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm). I have also paid some attention to SQL injection mentioned by Ollie.

```
create table so9at (
  id number(1),
  data varchar2(5)
);

insert into so9at values (1, 'A-AAA');
insert into so9at values (2, 'A-BBB');
insert into so9at values (3, 'A-CCC');

create table so9bt (
  id number(1),
  data varchar2(5)
);

insert into so9bt values (5, 'B-AAA');
insert into so9bt values (6, 'B-BBB');
insert into so9bt values (7, 'B-CCC');

create table secret_identities (
  cover_name varchar2(20),
  real_name varchar2(20)
);

insert into secret_identities values ('Batman', 'Bruce Wayne');
insert into secret_identities values ('Superman', 'Clark Kent');

/* This is a semi-secure version immune to certain kind of SQL injections. Note
that it can be still used to find information about any table that ends with
't'. */
create or replace function cursor_of (p_table_id in varchar2)
return sys_refcursor as
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
  v_stmt constant varchar2(32767) := 'select * from ' || dbms_assert.qualified_sql_name(p_table_id || 't');
begin
  open v_cur for v_stmt;
  return v_cur;
end;
/
show errors

/* This is an unsecure version vulnerable to SQL injection. */
create or replace function vulnerable_cursor_of (p_table_id in varchar2)
return sys_refcursor as
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
  v_stmt constant varchar2(32767) := 'select * from ' || p_table_id || 't';
begin
  open v_cur for v_stmt;
  return v_cur;
end;
/
show errors

create or replace procedure print_values_of (p_cur in sys_refcursor) as
  type rec_t is record (
    id number,
    data varchar2(32767)
  );
  v_rec rec_t;
begin
  fetch p_cur into v_rec;

  while p_cur%found loop
    dbms_output.put_line('id = ' || v_rec.id || ' data = ' || v_rec.data);
    fetch p_cur into v_rec;
  end loop;

end;
/
show errors

declare
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  v_cur := cursor_of('so9a');
  print_values_of(v_cur);
  close v_cur;

  v_cur := cursor_of('so9b');
  print_values_of(v_cur);
  close v_cur;

  /* SQL injection vulnerability */
  v_cur := vulnerable_cursor_of('secret_identities --');
  dbms_output.put_line('Now we have a cursor that reveals all secret identities. Just see DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS ...');
  close v_cur;

  /* SQL injection made (mostly) harmless - will throw ORA-44004: invalid qualified SQL name */
  v_cur := cursor_of('secret_identities --');
  close v_cur;
end;
/
```